# ColdFusion 11 RDS in Homesite

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Has anyone been able to get an RDS connection working between ColdFusion 11 and HomeSite?  If so, I'd sure appreciate some specifics.  I've tried about everything, and I get an error "HTTP Error :404".

Thanks.  -bg

Comment: Did you have this running with ColdFusion 10? I can't imagine that HomeSite would be able to make the RDS jump after the move to Tomcat.

Comment: Better suited for Server Fault

Comment: We are moving from CF9 to CF11, so I don't know about 10.  No problem with CF9.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working. It was a problem with the configuration on the server. It works now in ColdFusion Builder 3 AND HomeSite+.

Comment: It'd be helpful to others if you'd indicate what the configuration problem was and how you fixed it.

Comment: Any word on this. Trying to figure this out also

Answer (score 2):

CF6 through 9 used JRun, so I can image that HomeSite's RDS implementation was suited to that server. Now that CF 10 and 11 run on Tomcat instead of JRun, I can't imagine that the RDS connection will work. Nor can I see Adobe issuing a patch for a piece software they never supported.

If you want an IDE with ColdFusion 10/11 RDS support, you're going to have to bite the bullet and move to ColdFusion Builder. If you want a better editor and can do without the RDS support, I'd suggest Sublime Text.

Answer (score 0):

The following Apache directive fixed the 404 issue with RDS:

```
<Location "/CFIDE/main/ide.cfm">
  SetHandler jakarta-servlet
</Location>
```

Turns out Apache tries to verify that the file exists but this one doesn't, hence the 404.  The /CFIDE/main/ide.cfm location is mapped to the RDS servlet in the Tomcat config so you need to tell Apache to route requests to that location to Tomcat.